# Is the right hand side of an assignment operator always evaluated first?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, order-of-execution

Will right side always evaluated to ahead of left side? And then the result of right side will be passed on to left side. I am not talking about the exception such as `A[i]=i++`

I am talking about the normal cases:

```
A[i] = (j+32+43 & K); 
A[j] != (A[j] + A[k]);
```

will the right part of all these expression evaluated first and then the result is compared to the left side? (Always)

Comment: Right side of which operators exactly?

Comment: any operstor @YuHao if there is any general rule

Comment: In C, some items, like plain expressions evaluate right to left, however, there are several statements in C that evaluate left to right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the order of evaluation of assignment operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59722807/what-is-the-order-of-evaluation-of-assignment-operators)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general the order of evaluation of sub-expressions is unspecified, there are a few exceptions such as *logical and*, *logical or*, *comma operator*, etc...

Since you [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351162/will-right-hand-side-of-an-expression-always-evaluated-first/26351399#comment41362808_26351162) stated you are interested in the general rule:

> any operstor @YuHao if there is any general rule

that would be covered by the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.5` *Expressions* paragraph `3` which says (*emphasis mine going forward*):

> The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.74)
>   **Except as specified later** (for the function-call (), &&, ||, ?:, and
>   comma operators), **the order of evaluation of subexpressions and the
>   order in which side effects take place are both unspecified**.

this is basically the same in the [draft C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) expect C11 does not list the exceptions so quoting C99 is more convenient. Paragraph `3` in C11 says:

> The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.85)
>   **Except as specified later, side effects and value computations of
>   subexpressions are unsequenced**.86)

Specifically for *assignment operators* C99 says:

> The order of evaluation of the operands is unspecified [...]

and C11 says:

> [...] The evaluations of the operands are unsequenced.

Comment: this line of yours:`the order in which side effects take place are both unspecified` made everything clear.

Comment: @codejam.tk I added links to the draft C99 and C11 standards. I get all my draft standard links from [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/81656) which as far as I can tell links to every public draft standard.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no such guarantee, N1570 §6.5.16/p3 (emphasis mine):

> An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the
>   left operand. An assignment expression has the value of the left
>   operand after the assignment,111) but is not an lvalue. The type of an
>   assignment expression is the type the left operand would have after
>   lvalue conversion. The side effect of updating the stored value of the
>   left operand is sequenced after the value computations of the left and
>   right operands. **The evaluations of the operands are unsequenced**.

Note that assignment operator "consumes" two operands and has side-effect of modifying a lvalue.

Comment: everytime i ask questions on stackoverflow people copy and explain the content from original standard. I have K&R book. I don't think it has that documentation for standards. Can you tell me where can i read those standards book or pdf something. All of them.

Comment: @codejam.tk: Drafts are freely available from [WG14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards) website.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this today, and spent 1 hour debugging code like this:

```
int a[1], b=0;

a[b++] = b;
```

I expected a[0] to contain 0 after this, but the compiler actually decided to evaluate b++ first, then right side of assignment, and store result in a[0] (so b++ on the left side worked as it should). So this effectively became:

```
b++;
a[0] = b; // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the precedence and associativity of the operators involved.

A full list can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: This will depend mostly on the compiler implementation. Precedence and associativity are factors in the compiler's decision, but they don't define the order of evaluation.

Comment: @IdanArye - Have you any evidence for this? Are you saying that compilers can ignore precedence/associativity of the operators?

Comment: I'm not saying that compilers can ignore precedence and associativity - I'm saying these things are different from order of evaluation. If you have `a * b + c * d` the compiler can choose to evaluate `a * b` first then `c * d` then add them, or it can choose to evaluate `c * d` first then `a * b` then add them - and both choices respect precedence and associativity.

Comment: @IdanArye yaa i read that point in ANSI C. It depends (mostly) on the compiler implementation. But I am not sure if this word was mostly or sometimes.